# Grails - return an object containing other objects?

Tags: sql, grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm

I'm trying to pull back a compound object in Grails.

I have a User class, which looks like this.

```
public class User {
String email
String firstName
String lastName
String password
SortedSet tasks

static hasMany = [tasks: Task]

static constraints = {
    email (blank: false, email:true)
    firstName (blank: false)
    lastName (blank: false)
    password (blank: false)
    tasks (blank: true)
}

static mapping = {
    table 'User'
    firstName column:'FirstName'
    lastName column:'LastName'
    password column:'Password'
    email column:'Email'
    tasks column:'UserId'

}
```

I also have a Task class, which looks like this.

```
public class Task {

String imageUrl
String name
String shortDescription
String longDescription
Date dueDate
Boolean complete

static belongsTo = [User]

static constraints = {
    imageUrl (blank: true)
    name (blank: false, nullable: false)
    shortDescription (nullable: false)
    longDescription (nullable: false)
    dueDate (blank: false)
    complete (blank: false)

}

static mapping = {
    table 'Task'
    imageUrl column:'ImageUrl'
    name column:'Name'
    shortDescription column:'ShortDescription'
    longDescription column:'LongDescription'
    dueDate column:'DueDate'
    complete column:'Complete'
}
```

Each of those classes have separate controllers.

As you can see, a user has (contains) many tasks. That's why I'm using a SortedSet to contain all of the tasks.

**My question:** In the following UserController code, I need to collect all tasks for  **userToDisplay** in a SortedList. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Nothing is ever pulled back in the SortedSet.

```
def Login()
{

    if(request.method == 'POST')
    {
    def userToDisplay = User.findByEmailAndPassword(params.email, params.password)
    userToDisplay.Tasks = Task.findAllByUserId(userToDisplay.id)


        if(userToDisplay)
        { 
            //We have our user. Display his info.
        }
        else
        { 
            //We don't have our user. Display an error message.
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell me how to correct this. This seems exceedingly simple, and I'm not quite getting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

User already has: `static hasMany = [tasks: Task]` so you do not need to `Task.findAllByUserId(userToDisplay.id)` just:

```
def userToDisplay = User.findByEmailAndPassword(params.email, params.password)
def userTasksAsList
if(userToDisplay?.tasks.size())
    userTasksAsList = userToDisplay?.tasks as List

....
```

If you still want to find all tasks by User then make sure you add a back reference to Task class `static belongsTo = [user:User]` and then `Task.findAllByUser(userInstance)`